# jQueryUI Autocomplete error: this.source is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a live search function which searches through keys in a JSON fetched from a public api and I am using Jquery UI in order to do so however I am getting the following error, and I am not sure how to solve this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function

```html
<div class="live_search">
  <label for="search_player">Search a player </label>
  <input id="search_player">
</div>
```

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
var data;

request.open('GET', 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/', true)
request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    $(function() {
      data;
      $("#search_player").autocomplete({
        source: data.elements.first_name
      });
    });
  }
  console.log(data);
}
request.send();
```

Any ideas as to what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) for the autocomplete `source` option you can see the issue is because you're providing a single string value.

When providing a string it needs to be a valid URL so that the plugin can make a request to that endpoint to retrieve the data to fill the control with.

As the string you're providing is not a valid URL or an array, it's assumed that it's a function. Hence trying to invoke a string as though it's a function causes the error you see.

To fix this you need to provide a value to `source` in a format that it expects, as outlined by the documentation link above.

In addition, you can remove the document.ready event handler you define in the `onload` function, as it's redundant, and also the single line with `data;` as it doesn't do anything.

Comment: So do i put source : "url of the json" ?

Comment: Assuming it's in the right format for Datatables to parse, yes

Comment: I am not using datatables though, im using Jquery UI

Comment: Sorry, I meant Autocomplete :) No idea why I wrote Datatables there